# Javascript Canvas Viewport Camera for Top down RPG game

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas, html5-canvas

edit: what is my question exactly?
I want to create a "viewport" camera effect that will follow the player without moving the background

I'm adding a websocket support and will render more characters on the map - i need movement to happen based on the player and not the map - so that i can update the rest of the players with movement position correctly

original post:

I've gone over most other posts about this subject.
It seems that, everyone, has their own unique problem for their own unique implementation of the "Canvas topdown game".
That makes it really hard finding a solution for your problem without refactoring your whole code.

So hopefully you guys will be able to help me this time.

Simple game (so far) - utilizing Vue3 btw but that's besides the point - most of the code is just Vanilla stuff.

Simple topdown map.
X and Y Axis

What I'm doing in my implementation is taking a PNG I've created with the Tiled application

Zoomed in by about 400% - drawing it with ctx.drawImage

then I'm also setting boundaries

and then drawing the player

what I'm doing now is adding a "force" value to the x and y position on key pressed (WASD)
Which means the character moves on the map and collision detection works
what I want is the map to draw x amount of pixels based on where the character is positioned WITHOUT moving the map since I'm already implementing some SocketIO code to make this multiplayer

I'm really really lost here, not sure what I should be doing to make the map draw a viewport....

I hope some of this makes sense

Some code

```
function create() {
        const canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.getElementById("game") as HTMLCanvasElement;
        if (!canvas) return console.error("canvas is undefined");
        const ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = canvas.getContext("2d") as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
        ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        initializeGameWindow(canvas, ctx);
        setEvents(canvas, ctx);
        const playerSpriteWidth = 192;
        const playerSpriteHeight = 68;
        const spriteFrames = 4;
        background = new Sprite();
        player = new Sprite();
        update(canvas, ctx);
    }

    function update(canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => update(canvas, ctx));
        drawGame(canvas, ctx);
    }

    function drawGame(canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
        background.draw(ctx);
        boundaries.forEach((boundary) => {
            boundary.draw(ctx);
        });
        player.value.draw(ctx);
        let moving: boolean = true;
        player.value.moving = false;
        if (keys.w.pressed && lastKey.value === "w") {
            player.value.moving = true;
            player.value.image = player.value.sprites.up;
            for (let i = 0; i < boundaries.length; i++) {
                if (
                    rectengularCollision(player.value, {
                        ...boundaries[i],
                        position: { x: boundaries[i].position.x, y: boundaries[i].position.y + Sprite.force },
                    })
                ) {
                    moving = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!moving) return;
            player.value.position.y -= Sprite.force;
            
        } else if (keys.a.pressed && lastKey.value === "a") {
            player.value.moving = true;
            player.value.image = player.value.sprites.left;
            for (let i = 0; i < boundaries.length; i++) {
                if (
                    rectengularCollision(player.value, {
                        ...boundaries[i],
                        position: { x: boundaries[i].position.x + Sprite.force, y: boundaries[i].position.y },
                    })
                ) {
                    moving = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!moving) return;
            player.value.position.x -= Sprite.force;
            
        } else if (keys.s.pressed && lastKey.value === "s") {
            player.value.moving = true;
            player.value.image = player.value.sprites.down;
            for (let i = 0; i < boundaries.length; i++) {
                if (
                    rectengularCollision(player.value, {
                        ...boundaries[i],
                        position: { x: boundaries[i].position.x, y: boundaries[i].position.y - Sprite.force },
                    })
                ) {
                    moving = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!moving) return;
            player.value.position.y += Sprite.force;
            
        } else if (keys.d.pressed && lastKey.value === "d") {
            player.value.moving = true;
            player.value.image = player.value.sprites.right;
            for (let i = 0; i < boundaries.length; i++) {
                if (
                    rectengularCollision(player.value, {
                        ...boundaries[i],
                        position: { x: boundaries[i].position.x - Sprite.force, y: boundaries[i].position.y },
                    })
                ) {
                    moving = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!moving) return;
            player.value.position.x += Sprite.force;
            
        }
    }
    
    export class Sprite {
        static force: number = 3; // speed, velocity, acceleration, etc.
        frames: number;
        spriteIteration: number = 0;
        elapsed: number = 0;
        defaultSrc: string;
        image: HTMLImageElement;
        sprites: { up: HTMLImageElement; down: HTMLImageElement; left: HTMLImageElement;             
        right: HTMLImageElement };
        position: { x: number; y: number };
        width: number = 0;
        height: number = 0;
        moving: boolean = false;
        constructor(
            position: { x: number; y: number },
            src : string,
            frames: number = 1,
            sprites: { up: string; down: string; left: string; right: string } = { up:           
            "", down: "", left: "", right: "" },
            ) {
                this.defaultSrc = src;
                this.moving = false;
                const { up, down, left, right } = this.initSprites(sprites);
                this.sprites = { up, down, left, right };
                this.image = down;
                this.frames = frames;
                this.position = position;
                    this.image.onload = () => {
                    this.width = this.image.width / this.frames;
                    this.height = this.image.height;
                };
        }

    draw(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
        ctx.drawImage(
            // src
            this.image,
            // crop from x axis
            this.spriteIteration * this.width,
            // crop from y axis
            0,
            // crop width 
            this.image.width / this.frames,
            // crop height
            this.image.height,
            // x position on canvas
            this.position.x,
            // y position on canvas
            this.position.y,
            // width on canvas
            this.image.width / this.frames,
            //  height on canvas
            this.image.height,
        );
    }

    initSprites(sprites: { up: string; down: string; left: string; right: string }) {
        const up = new Image();
        up.src = sprites.up;
        const down = new Image();
        down.src = sprites.down !== "" ? sprites.down : this.defaultSrc;
        const left = new Image();
        left.src = sprites.left;
        const right = new Image();
        right.src = sprites.right;
        return { up, down, left, right };
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: I want to create a "viewport" camera effect that will follow the player without moving the background

I'm adding a websocket support and will render more characters on the map - i need movement to happen based on the player and not the map - so that i can update the rest of the players with movement position correctly

Comment: @LiadGoren- That's actually a statement. All you've done is tell us what you'd like to do and dump a heap of code. What do you want to know? What can we tell you that will help? Is it the concept of windowing that you don't understand? Is it a matter wondering if you should do the translations yourself or leave it to the canvas element? Your goal is clear. What step you'd like help to take next in order to realize this goal is not.

Comment: I'd like to know what I need to change in my code in order for the window - the UI - the view that the client that connects to my "game" (website) sees moves with his character - with his character being in the center on the map.

so that the client sees new parts of the "map" (the png) while having an exact location of all other players in the map @HelderSepulveda

Comment: you should read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example focus on the minimal part, questions with hundred+  lines of code are hard to follow! ... just reduce your problem, to simplify it you can start by instead of images just draw rectangles or circles, remove everything that is not absolutely necessary to show the problem, if SocketIO & multiplayer is not the problem don't even mention it, that is just a distraction.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't included a runnable snippet for me to work with, here's a very generic example that shows how you can use `CanvasRenderingContext2D`'s transformation methods to change the viewport of a scene.

In `draw`, you'll see:

- Reset the transform to use the center of the `<canvas>` as `(0, 0)` using [`setTransform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform)
- To draw from the perspective of a player:

  - translate the context by `-x` and `-y` multiplied by the zoom factor
  - scale the canvas with the zoom factor

```js
// Initialize
const cvs = document.createElement("canvas");
cvs.width = 200;
cvs.height = 200;
const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

// State
const players = [
  [-20, -30, "green"],
  [50, 70, "blue"]
];

let viewport = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  zoom: 1
};

// Drawing methods
const clear = () => {
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillRect(-cvs.width / 2, -cvs.height / 2, cvs.width, cvs.height);
};

const drawMap = () => {
  const w = cvs.width - 25;
  const h = cvs.height - 25;
  
  ctx.fillStyle = "#efefef";
  ctx.fillRect(
   -w / 2,
   -h / 2,
   w,
   h
  );
}

const drawPlayers = () => {
  for (const [x, y, color] of players) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 10, Math.PI * 2, 0);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

const drawCenter = () => {
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)";
  ctx.fillRect(-1, -15, 2, 30);
  ctx.fillRect(-15, -1, 30, 2);
}

const draw = () => {
  // Zoom out and set (0, 0) to center of canvas
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, cvs.width / 2, cvs.height / 2);
  clear();
  
  const { zoom, x, y } = viewport;
  ctx.translate(-x * zoom, -y * zoom);
  ctx.scale(zoom, zoom);
  
  drawMap();
  drawPlayers();
  
  // For debugging: mark the center of the canvas
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, cvs.width / 2, cvs.height / 2);
  drawCenter();
}

draw();

document.body.appendChild(cvs);

// UI
const updateViewport = () => {
  const centerValue = document.querySelector("input[name=center]:checked").value;
  
  const [x, y] = players[centerValue] || [0, 0];
  const zoom = document.querySelector("input[type=range]").valueAsNumber;
  
  viewport = { x: x, y: y, zoom };
  draw();
};

document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("input", updateViewport);
});
```

```css
body { display: flex; }
canvas { border: 1px solid red; position: relative; }
fieldset { margin-bottom: 1rem; }
```

```html
<div> 
  <fieldset>
    <legend>View center:</legend>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="-1" name="center" checked> Map
    </label>

    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="0" name="center"> Green player
    </label>

    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="1" name="center"> Blue player
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Zoom</legend> 
    <input type="range" min="0.1" max ="3" step="0.1" value="1">
  </fieldset>
  
</div>
```

Comment: This is more than I can ask for ! I appreciate that! thank you. I'll look into it